# How to make a coding using firebase that update the data not replace the data?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a question. My apps are currently using firebase database. Here is the flow on how it runs. The user will make an evaluation of a poster based on the group names. So one group will have more than one user that will evaluates them. But currently in my apps, only one user can evaluates one group. I want everytime the user add data (comment and score) it will update the data. Not replace the data. I would greatly appreciate it if you give me some feedback on this.

Here is my coding

```
import android.content.Intent;
//import android.graphics.Color;
//import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class FormActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//DatabaseReference Db;
//FirebaseHelper helper;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
ChildEventListener childEventListener;

private EditText et1, et_comment;
private Spinner sp;
private Boolean loop = false;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
private String groupKey;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
private TextView tv_outcome;
private ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> groupNames = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> posterIds = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);
  // getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#E71E67")));

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()== null){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, Login.class));
    }

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    final RadioGroup rg1 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);
    final RadioGroup rg2 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg2);
    final RadioGroup rg3 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg3);
    final RadioGroup rg4 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg4);
    final RadioGroup rg5 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg5);
    final RadioGroup rg6 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg6);
    final RadioGroup rg7 = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg7);
    et1 = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.et1);
    et_comment=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_comment);

    tv_outcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_outcome);

    Button btn_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
    sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.group);

    //Db=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    //helper=new FirebaseHelper(Db);

    getKeys();
    getGroups();

    sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
            groupKey = keys.get(sp.getSelectedItemPosition());
            Log.d("groupKey", groupKey);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });

    btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String value1 = ((RadioButton) findViewById(rg1.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
            String value2 = ((RadioButton) findViewById(rg2.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
            String value3 = ((RadioButton) findViewById(rg3.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
            String value4 = ((RadioButton) findViewById(rg4.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
            String value5 = ((RadioButton) findViewById(rg5.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
            String value6 = ((RadioButton) findViewById(rg6.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
            String value7 = ((RadioButton) findViewById(rg7.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();


            float marks = Float.parseFloat(value1) + Float.parseFloat(value2) + Float.parseFloat(value3) + Float.parseFloat(value4) + Float.parseFloat(value5) + Float.parseFloat(value6) + Float.parseFloat(value7);

            //calculate total

            float total = makeCalculations(marks);

            tv_outcome.setText(String.valueOf(total));

            saveEvaluation();
        }
    });

}

  private void saveEvaluation(){

 //       String Name = et1.getText().toString().trim();

    Float Total = Float.valueOf(tv_outcome.getText().toString());

    String Comment = et_comment.getText().toString().trim();

    Evaluation evaluation =  new Evaluation(Total,Comment);

    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

//        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Name)){
//            et1.setError("Please Enter Group Name");
//            et1.requestFocus();
//            return;
//        }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(Comment)){
        et_comment.setError("Please Enter Your Comment");
        et_comment.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    assert user != null;

//  databaseReference.child("Evaluation").
//child(groupKey).setValue(evaluation);

databaseReference.child("Evaluation").child(groupKey).child("total").
setValue(Total);


databaseReference.child("Evaluation").child(groupKey).child("comment").
setValue(Comment);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Information Saved...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}

private float makeCalculations(float marks) {

    return (marks / 35 * 100);

}

private void getKeys() {
    childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            keys.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    databaseReference.child("Evaluation").addChildEventListener(childEventListener);
}

private void getGroups() {
    databaseReference.child("Evaluation").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String posterId = "";
            String group = "";

            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                posterId = snapshot.child("posterID").getValue().toString();
                group = snapshot.child("group").getValue().toString();

                if(!posterIds.contains(posterId)) {
                    posterIds.add(posterId);
                    groupNames.add(group);
                }
            }

            addData(posterId, group);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

private void addData(String id, String group) {
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, groupNames);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);

    Log.d("LoadSpinner", "Ayyee");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used the Firebase JAVA SDK, so I don't the exact API but I think you need to change at least the following lines of code

```
databaseReference.child("Evaluation").child(groupKey).child("total").
setValue(Total);


databaseReference.child("Evaluation").child(groupKey).child("comment").
setValue(Comment);
```

to

```
databaseReference.child("Evaluation").child(groupKey).child(user.getUid()).child("total").
setValue(Total);


databaseReference.child("Evaluation").child(groupKey).child(user.getUid()).child("comment").
setValue(Comment);
```

where `userKey` is a unique identifier for the user who is making the evaluation. Then you will also need to change how you retrieve different evaluations by retrieving all the evaluations and merge them together.

Comment: do i need to make a declaration for userKey? when i run the code the new data (comment, total) it still replace the old one.Btw, thank you.

Comment: `userKey` is a string that uniquely identifies the user. I just checked, for your code, it would be `user.getUid()`. I have updated the code as well with this change.

Comment: do you mean .child(user.getUid())?